# How to return an index within an ArrayList based on an attribute of the elements it holds

Tags: java, arraylist

**is it possible to determine the ArrayList-index of an element inside the ArrayList based on one of its attributes?**

In my particular case **I have an Object "worker" with the attributes "name" and "worker_id"**. The worker_id is an ID I get from the database.

Since the **first worker-object inside the ArrayList doesn't necessarily start with 0** (and may have gaps), it's not the same ID as the index each element has inside this ArrayList.

Now **I want to determine this particular index of a worker-object inside the ArrayList based on its attribute "worker_id"**. However: since the list can be very long, I'd like to not have to iterate over the worker-ArrayList everytime.

Using a HashMap might be a solution, but I'd like to use an ArrayList if possible, because I normally won't need a key (except in this case).

Any suggestions are welcome!

Thank you in advance,
Igor.

Comment: Isn't the `worker_id` the key?

Comment: is the list sorted by worker_id?

Comment: The list is sorted by worker_id; however: worker_id is not the key, since worker_id can be 5, 7, 12, 15 etc. It's the id of the worker_table - and that id is on auto_increment, therefore starts off at 1 and may contain gaps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Since the first worker-object inside the ArrayList doesn't necessarily start with 0 (and may have gaps), it's not the same ID as the index each element has inside this ArrayList.*

It sounds to me that the **list is at least sorted**? In that case, you could use a **binary search**, which is slightly faster than a linear scan of the list.

Another option is to define two workers to be `equal` if they have the same `worker_id`. Then you could simply do `int index = workerList.indexOf(new Worker(idToSearchFor));`

> *Using a HashMap might be a solution, but I'd like to use an ArrayList if possible, because I normally won't need a key (except in this case).*

Well, to be honest, when I use a map it is **seldom because I *couldn't* do it** with a list, but rather because **the interface of a map is nicer to work with**, and results in cleaner code. So, even though you may think that a HashMap is an overkill, it may be worth it, solely because it's slightly more logical and the code ends up being a bit easier to read.

Comment: Actually all of the solutions posted here are interesting. I try to overwrite equal and use indexOf with some sort of "dummy" worker-object, that only contains a valid worker_id. Thanks for all other suggestions though :).

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). This offers the best of both worlds: it can behave as a list due to its predictable iteration order *and* it offers fast (O(1)) key based lookup at the same time.

The price is, as can be expected, a slight performance penalty (compared to `ArrayList`).

Comment: I'll look into this. However: I am using Google Web Toolkit and therefore it might not be implemented in there - I'll have to check. I'd prefer to keep the ArrayList though. Thank you very much for your answer though :).

Answer (score 0):

You need to check every object for it's id. There is no direct way i guess.
Iterate through all the objects and check for the id.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
List<Worker> workers = // ...
for (int i = 0; i < workers.size(); i++) {
    if (/* ... */) {
        return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's something I came across too, but thought there must be a smarter solution than just iterating hundrets of times through the list.

Answer (score 0):

`int find(List <A> list, Object sth)
{
Iterator it = list.iterator();
int index = 0;
while(it.hasNext());
A current = it.next();
if (el.getSth().equals(element)) {
return index;
}
index++;
}
return -1;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Create the List as big as the largest worker_id value. while inserting the object, insert it at worker_id number.
like

list.add(obj.worker_id,obj);

while retrieving 

list.get(obj.worker_id);

yes, its not space effecient solution, the space efficient solution is to use the Hashmap (or its variant) as everyone else have already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two choices:

1. Build an index. A hash is a decent mechanism for accessing an index, but there are others. A simple sparse array might work in this context, for example.
2. Search for the matching element. A linear scan is O(n) but a binary search is O(log n) so will be better if your list is sorted (assuming any non-trivial length).